# Where is my databricks notebook in azure

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake

After creating the notebook in Azure databrick's cluster, I can't see it on the portal. I can see on the label that notebook count is 1 and it is not allowing me to create another notebook with the same name.

[image]

But I am not able to access it by any mean.

Can anyone please help in this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to see your notebooks in the Workspace tab. The Notebooks count in Cluster tab seems to be not accurate.

Comment: I cannot see notebooks over there as well.

Comment: @Pragmatic Could you describe how did you created your Notebook?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you doing it from the company, if so try from home. There seems to be an issue with WinSockets one of the sympoms is that the databricks never connects. 
see this [Azure databricks never connects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50578785/azure-databricks-never-connects)