# Azure databricks never connects

Tags: azure, databricks

I have created an Azure DataBricks cluster, which is in running state. But I cannot see shared, users and newly created notebooks under workspace. In fact, I can see a connecting... image on top left corner.

[image]

Please help.

Comment: Do you want to connect the cluster instances ?

Comment: I want to create notebook, associate it with cluster and work with it. But while creating notebooks, they do not show up under workspance. Since I cannot see users, I cannot create private notebook as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For us the problem was Websocket traffic being blocked on our proxy servers by McAfee Web Gateway.  The solution was to selctively allow Websocket traffic as described here:

https://kc.mcafee.com/corporate/index?page=content&id=KB84052&actp=null&showDraft=false&platinum_status=false&locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US

Excerpt from that article:

> **CAUTION**: Be careful in allowing a WebSockets connection through MWG,
>   so you do not open a security hole inside your setup. We recommended
>   you do not allow WebSockets in general, but allow only the
>   destinations you really want to use WebSockets.
>
> To import the required rule set: Log in to MWG. Select Policy, Rule
>   Sets, Common Rules. Click Add and select Rule Set from Library. In the
>   Overview section, expand Common Rules. Select WebSocket Handling and
>   click OK. Place this rule set into your Common Rules set.
>
> ....

Answer (score 0):

To create a new notebook and attach it to a Spark cluster in **Azure DataBricks**, select *New* ➡ *Notebook* on the landing page in your DataBricks portal.

[image]

Give the notebook a unique name, and click *Create*.

[image]

Once the notebook has been created, select *Detached* in the upper left-hand corner, and then select the cluster you wish to connect to. If the circle next to cluster's name is grey, it must be restarted.

[image]

For full documentation on working with DataBricks on Azure, including a [Quickstart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-databricks/quickstart-create-databricks-workspace-resource-manager-template) for running a Spark SQL job, check out http://learn.microsoft.com.

Answer (score 0):

We found the issue. This was due to some blocked outbound access that our IT had configured. When we tried from home network, it worked.

Thanks

Comment: I have the same issue from a certain network.  What exactly was the issue?  Please add the detail and then this answer will be useful for other users!

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait. Starting a cluster usually takes at least 1 minute. This is why you see "running".

For created notebooks, I assume you have already created one notebook. You need to click "workspace" and expand those user emails. You will your notebook may be under one of those user emails.